# How to get an instance of a Reflection.Emit type?

Tags: c#, interface, reflection.emit

So I have a class:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public string foo {get;}
    public MyClass bar {get;}
}
```

And an interface:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    string foo {get;}
}
```

And a system to create an emitted type:

```
    private static Type MakeDynamicType<T>() where T : class
    {
        var myType = GetTypeBuilder();

        myType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(T));

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in properties)
            AddProperty(myType, property, typeof(T));

        AddCtor(myType, typeof(T));

        return myType.CreateType();
    }

    private static void AddCtor(TypeBuilder myType, Type inputParamType)
    {
        var myCtor = myType.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, null);
        var ilGenerator = myCtor.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }


    private const MethodAttributes GET_SET_ATTR = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                                                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual;

    private static void AddProperty(TypeBuilder myType, PropertyInfo property, Type interfaceType)
    {
        var myField = myType.DefineField($"m_{property.Name}", property.PropertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        var myProperty = myType.DefineProperty(property.Name, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, property.PropertyType,
            parameterTypes: null);

        var interfaceGetMethod = interfaceType.GetMethod($"get_{property.Name}");
        if (interfaceGetMethod != null)
            AddGetter(myType, property, myField, myProperty, interfaceGetMethod);

        var interfaceSetMethod = interfaceType.GetMethod($"set_{property.Name}");
        if (interfaceSetMethod != null)
            AddSetter(myType, property, myField, myProperty, interfaceSetMethod);
    }

    private static void AddGetter(TypeBuilder myType, PropertyInfo property, FieldInfo myField,
        PropertyBuilder myProperty, MethodInfo interfaceGetMethod)
    {
        var myGet = myType.DefineMethod($"get_{property.Name}", GET_SET_ATTR, property.PropertyType,
            Type.EmptyTypes);
        var getIl = myGet.GetILGenerator();
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, myField);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        myProperty.SetGetMethod(myGet);
        myType.DefineMethodOverride(myGet, interfaceGetMethod);
    }

    private static void AddSetter(TypeBuilder myType, PropertyInfo property, FieldInfo myField,
        PropertyBuilder myProperty, MethodInfo interfaceSetMethod)
    {
        var mySet = myType.DefineMethod($"set_{property.Name}", GET_SET_ATTR, returnType: null,
            new[] { property.PropertyType });
        var setIl = mySet.GetILGenerator();
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, myField);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        myProperty.SetSetMethod(mySet);
        myType.DefineMethodOverride(mySet, interfaceSetMethod);
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var myDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
        var myAsmName = new AssemblyName("MyDynamicAssembly");

        var myAsmBuilder = myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        var myModBuilder = myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(myAsmName.Name, myAsmName.Name + ".dll");

        return myModBuilder.DefineType("MyDynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);
    }
```

So now how do I create an instance of my reflected type from an IMyClass type reference to a MyClass object?

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToInterfacedObjects<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
    {
        var myType = MakeDynamicType<T>();

        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var datum in data)
        {
            list.Add((T)myType.GetValue(datum));//What do I write for GetValue??
        }

        return list;
    }
```

My goal is to start with an `IMyClass` which has an underlying type of `MyClass`, which has both foo and bar, and end with an `IMyClass` which has an underlying type of an emitted type, which has `foo` but not `bar`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205714/discussion-on-question-by-sarov-how-to-get-an-instance-of-a-reflection-emit-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an implementation for `MakeDynamicType<T>`, and assuming your interface has only simple `{get; set;}` properties, wouldn't this be as simple as:

```
public static IList<T> ToInterfacedObjects<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
{
    var myType = MakeDynamicType<T>();
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach (var datum in data)
    {
        var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var val = pi.GetValue(datum);
            pi.SetValue(obj, val);
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `myType` is of type `System.Type` whereas `T` is `IMyClass`, so I can't put `myType` into `list`.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to create an instance of `myType`.  See update.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question,  However, I would be the OP could get away with just creating an adapter instead of using relection

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The `Activator.CreateInstance(myType)` is throwing an `TargetInvocationException` with an inner `InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'`. Any idea why?

Comment: Not without seeing `MakeDynamicType`.  Even if you emitted the IL for a new type, it wouldn't be JITted until needed, so could be an error in the IL.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This time SO let me add the code for `MakeDynamicType`. I've updated my Question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Found it! Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Cool.  Although it's probably easier to customize your serializer than to generate a type specifically for serialization.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Definitely. My first attempt was just using Newtonsoft with a custom ContractResolver. That didn't work for Telerik Grids, though, which need to provide to provide a `DataSourceRequest` to make a `DataSourceResult` to serialize.